# Laravel - Use Class like Auth

Tags: laravel-5

I have a Class Post. Created the Model, Restfull Resource Controller.
Now i implemented the show function in my Resource Controller.
So if someone routes to `/post/234234` he will automatically see the post.

But now I want to create a new static function on myself. Let's call it `myFunction()`. I don't like to hand over the `id` all the time. Isn't there a possibilty to create a object or something like that, so I can use  this like that `Post::myFunction()`, without hand over the id all the time.

It's similar to the `Auth` Class. I mean I can check if the user is logged in just like that `Auth::check()`.

**Update**
Let's describe it more clearly. This is my PostController@show:

```
public function show($id)
{

    //Get board information
    $post = Post::find($id);    

    //Return view
    return view('post')->with(array(
        'posts' => $post
    ));
}
```

It shows just the post. In my view I have a button called `Follow up`. I only want to show it, if he didn't follow up the post yet. Now i thought about to edit the Model `Post.php` and add a static function `followed()` so i can just do this in the view:

```
@if(Post::followed())
    <button>Follow up</button>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can simply create a static function:

```
public static function myFunction(){

}
```

Just note that this function will be called in static context so you there's no `$this` available.

Alternatively you can create a Facade (`Auth` is a Facade). The process is described pretty well in the [documentation about facades](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/facades)

---

As for your specific case I don't even think a static method is needed. Since you pass `$post` to the view you can just add a regular public method:

```
public function isFollowing(){

}
```

And then do this in your view:

```
@if(!$post->isFollowing())
    <button>Follow up</button>
@endif
```

Comment: Yep i already create a static function. My wish is that i don't have to hand over the `id` like in the show as parameter.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. Can you please edit your question and add some more code?

Comment: Makes sense. But how does the `isFollowing()` function looks like? Where can i my entry find by id?

Comment: Well that mostly depends on your logic. You can retrieve the post's id with `$this->id`